# PHP MySQL Search Form Select Field and Search Term, Delimiter In Where Clause

Tags: php, mysql

I want to allow a user to search a table by selecting a field name from a dropdown list, then entering the term to search for in that field. The problem I'm having is that some fields are strings and some are numbers. When I construct the WHERE clause from the $_GET variables, I don't know how to delimit the search term because I can't come up with a good way to determine if the field selected by the user is numeric or string.

This is the search form:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
  <label for="search_field">Search:</label>
  <select name="search_field">
  <?php
    $fields = $res->fetch_fields();
    foreach($fields AS $f) {
      echo '<option value="' . $f->name . '">' . $f->name . '</option>\n';  
    }
  ?>
  </select>
  <label for="search_for">For:</label>
  <input type="text" name="search_for" />
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

The php file processes the search variables like this:

```
if(isset($_GET['search_field']) and isset($_GET['search_for'])) {
  $sql_where = "AND " . $_GET['search_field'] . ' = ' . $_GET['search_for'] . ' ';
}

$sql = $sql . $sql_where;
```

The query works fine for numeric fields, but not string fields. I could put quotes around the search_for term, but then numeric fields wouldn't work. There has got to be a way to do this. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you know from search_field parameter that which type of value search_for will have? If so than you can have if condition based on that search_field value. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Just use `is_numeric` function to determine if its an number or string:

```
if(isset($_GET['search_field']) and isset($_GET['search_for'])) {
  if(is_numeric($_GET['search_for']))
  $sql_where = 'AND ' . $_GET['search_field'] . ' =  . $_GET['search_for'] . ';
  else{
     $sql_where = 'AND ' . $_GET['search_field'] . ' = ' . '.$_GET['search_for'] . ' ';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if $_GET['search_for'] is numeric in php using is_numeric

```
if(isset($_GET['search_field']) and isset($_GET['search_for'])) {
    $sql_where = "AND " . $_GET['search_field'] . ' = ' .
    (is_numeric($_GET['search_for']) ? $_GET['search_for'] : '"' .
    $_GET['search_for'] . '"' ) . ' ';
}
```

Also if you always delimit the search_for with quotes it will work with numeric values you can try it. I just wanted to show you the is_numeric function as well

Comment: Thanks. Putting quotes around search_for does seem to work regardless of the datatype of the table column being searched. Last night it didn't seem to work for comparisons to columns typed as int or double, but today it does. I must have been tired.

Answer (score 0):

You know your code has security problems, don't you?

But to solve your problem just do

```
$search_for = is_numeric($_GET['search_for'])?$_GET['search_for']:"'".addslashes($_GET['search_for'])."'";
$sql_where = 'AND `' . $_GET['search_field'] . '` = ' . $search_for . ' ';
```

Comment: I had suspicions about security problems, but I don't know what they are or how to fix them. I read somewhere never to use PHP_SELF. I don't know why. Also GET vs POST? My last php mysql project was at least 5 years ago, and I'm relearning. If you could point me to some info on coding for a reasonable amount of security, I'd be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: You are inserting external code directly on you query.
Someone can search in the search_field something like '1 or search_for'. it will show everything. But in worst case, they can delete all your database, see your user, change a password, wherever they want to. 
My recommendation is use PDO or mysqli. and search 'php mysql avoid sql injection'